# How to enable GZIP Compression on Sitecore 10.1 hosted in containers

Tags: gzip

I am exploring ways to enhance the speed of my Sitecore pages by implementing `compression techniques`.

I have added the configuration mentioned below to the `Web.config` file, but it seems that the expected results have not been achieved so far (Not compressing the pages).

If anyone has encountered a similar issue and discovered a solution, I would greatly appreciate your insights and guidance.  Thank you!

```
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" staticCompressionDisableCpuUsage="95" staticCompressionEnableCpuUsage="60" dynamicCompressionDisableCpuUsage="95" dynamicCompressionEnableCpuUsage="50" xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="image/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="image/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" xdt:Transform="Insert"/> </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable compression with the web.config but it can depend on the permissions on the server allows sites. You should also check for these settings.

Select the site and click the compression.

[image]

Enable both the compressions available.

[image]

The Compression role should be installed at the server role as follows.

[image]

See if this helps you:

Comment: Thank you Sumit. I did check the IIS configurations Static and Dynamic compressions are enabled but still not working